# URL Query String - Phone Number

Tags: database, urls

How can I add a phone number in a URL query string in CiviCRM?

Goal:  To bring up all records associated with that number

Thank you,

Laurie

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "all records", but the custom search called full-text search (under Search - Custom Searches) can be made to run via url like so:

https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=15&text=894-1515&table=Contact&force=1&reset=1

That will bring up the contact with phone 894-1515.

If you want to include activities and such, then leave out the "table=Contact" part.

Comment: Thanks.   What I meant ... any record associated with that phone number.   There could be up to 50 records with the same phone number but different names associated with it.

Comment: The above will do that.

Comment: I do not normally work on CiviCRM.   My company does use it but not on my projects.  I was asked to help the team out.  Please excuse my little knowledge.  I tried the following link and got a message "sorry we are not able to provide".  ... EdwardsHeart/index.php?q=civicrm/contact/search/custom&text=262-268-5100&reset=1&force=1

Comment: My field is web development, databases and other market research software.

Comment: You need the ?csid=15 part included in the url. That tells it which custom search to use, and 15 is the built-in fulltext search.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!  Thank you so much.

Comment: beware missing out contacts that have the number but formatted differently

Answer (score 1):

LAE, You can do this in many ways

1. As suggested by Demerit you can use Full text search and append in url.
2. If you are using Drupal, then you can use Views to create list of contact and then use CONTEXTUAL FILTERS to filter based on arguments from URL

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks.  I will give this a try